# Angular 12: ng test - code coverage : TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'initialize')

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, karma-jasmine

I'm getting error code coverage console:  TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'initialize')
I'm calling service method to component.ts file

component.ts file

```
this.myAuth = this.myService.getDetails();
 this.myAuth.myAccess$.pipe(takeUntil(1)).subscribe((data) => {})
```

component.spec.ts

```
it('should called - myService', inject([myService], (service: myService) => {
    component.myAuth = service.getDetails();
    service.getDetails().myAccess$.pipe(takeUntil(1)).subscribe(value => {
      expect(value).toEqual(value);
    });
  }));
```

I'm written above code but I'm getting error - how to written test case for this ?

I need to resolve console error and code coverage red color lines remove. please guide me how to resolve this

Answer (score 0):

Update your component to handle potential undefined values:
Modify your component to check if this.myAuth is defined before subscribing to myAccess$
Update the service to return a mock object:
In your test, you need to provide a mock object for myService that returns a defined object with a myAccess$ property. You can use Jasmine's spy to create a mock service.

```js
it('should call myService', () => {
  const mockAuthService = jasmine.createSpyObj('myService', ['getDetails']);
  const mockAuthData = { myAccess$: of({}) }; // Replace this with your mock data

  mockAuthService.getDetails.and.returnValue(mockAuthData);

  const component = new YourComponent(mockAuthService);

  component.ngOnInit(); // Call the component's ngOnInit or the method where you use myAuth

  // Your expectations here for Example
component.myAuth.myAccess$.pipe(takeUntil(1)).subscribe((value) => {
    expect(value).toEqual({});
});
```

By following these steps, you should be able to resolve the console error and write proper test cases for your component. Make sure to replace {} in the test cases with the expected data you want to use for testing.

Comment: above solution not working

Comment: if there is an error in the console, or are you suggesting that the logic in the provided code is not working as intended?